# Flash Builder: Network Monitor - not showing raw data for AMF?

Tags: flash-builder, amf

I've built a basic RPC program using FluorineFX (.NET) on the backend for my AMF service. Everything works fine, i.e. I can make calls to the exposed functions.

However, when I looked at Network Monitor in Flash Builder to further examine the network traffic, and then view the Raw Data for the AMF response, it doesn't seem to be compressed/encoded. Also, the response size matches the non-compressed content. My understanding is that these things would be binary. Is there something wrong with my solution or assumptions?

Example: a response (some line breaks added) containing a short array (notice the unencoded body content):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 27 Aug 2010 15:06:49 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/x-amf
Content-Length: 363

Flex Message (flex.messaging.messages.AcknowledgeMessage)     
clientId = 29eb2c7f-974b-4bae-8d28-98d4b4dd0547    
correlationId = B556E5C3-5476-A92C-2CEC-B4163ABCD1C8    
destination = fluorine    
messageId = 92675e09-0bc0-498f-b017-7e601b740563    
timestamp = 250290640    
timeToLive = 0    
body = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]    
hdr(DSId) = 6b42848939804b7592eb956797d4eef4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Network Monitor (available only in Flash Builder Premium) doesn't ever actually show raw AMF data. However, I was mostly interested in response size (i.e. for optimization), which is available. The **Response Size (bytes)** in the **Tree View** shows the size of *unencoded* response, but you can get the *encoded* size from the **Content-Length** line in the **Raw View**.